# Branch Deferred deep linking not working for IOS Cordova phoneGap ionic plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, deep-linking, branch.io

I am using Branch.Io for deep linking using the cordova phoneGap plugin v6.

I am having issues with deferred deep linking specifically in iOS and get the error **"Property 'checkPasteboardOnInstall' does not exist on type 'BranchIo'"**.

The below code works fine and I get the expected data from my deeplink successfully if the app is already installed.

```
this.branch.initSession().then(res => {
    var1 = res['id'];
    var2 = res['type'];
    
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

However, when I try to use the NativeLink™ Deferred Deep Linking and add the below line of code - as described in the documentation - , I get the error **"Property 'checkPasteboardOnInstall' does not exist on type 'BranchIo'"**.

`this.branch.checkPasteboardOnInstall();`

Appreciate any inputs.

Apologies if my post is not formatted correctly, this is my first time posting.

Regards,

Pranay.

Comment: As outlined in the document here : https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/cordova-phonegap-ionic#nativelink-deferred-deep-linking-ios-only

The checkPasteBoardOnInstall method should be implemented in your native iOS SDK code